# In a separable Hilbert space, can you write an operator from $\mathcal H$ to $\mathcal H$ as a column-finite matrix?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

In this question, we are representing an operator $T$ as a matrix with respect to an orthonormal basis $\left\{e_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$. To do so, we let $t_{ij} = \langle T(e_j),e_i\rangle$. The question is asking us to show that the orthonormal basis can be chosen such that the number of non-zero entries in each column is finite. So this basically amounts to finding an orthonormal basis such that $\langle T(e_j),e_i\rangle$ is $0$ for all but finitely many elements of the basis.

I'm not entirely sure how to begin for this question. My approach was to first find such a basis for $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and then maybe use the isomorphism between $\mathcal H$ and $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, but I wasn't even able to get that far.

Comment: I think it may be possible with finite-rank operators.

Answer (score 0):

Begin with some orthonormal basis $(e_n)$. Then form another ONB $\mathcal F$ by the following algorithm:

1. $\mathcal F=()$, empty sequence.
2. Find the smallest $n$ such that $e_n$ is not in the span of $\mathcal F$. Add it to the end of $\mathcal F$ and apply Gram-Schmidt.
3. In the finite sequence $\mathcal F=(f_k)$, find the smallest $k$ such that $Tf_k$ is not in the span of $\mathcal F$. Add $Tf_k$ to the end of $\mathcal F$ and apply Gram-Schmidt. If there is no such $k$, skip this step.
4. Return to step 2.

Okay, this is not technically an algorithm because it never terminates. But you can check that it creates an ONB with the desired property. Completeness is assured by step 2, while the finite-columnness comes from step 3: the image of every element of $\mathcal F$ is in the span of finitely many elements.